# Convert bytes to int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, type-conversion, byte

I'm currently working on an encryption/decryption program and I need to be able to convert bytes to an integer. I know that:

```
bytes([3]) = b'\x03'
```

Yet I cannot find out how to do the inverse. What am I doing terribly wrong?

Comment: There is also the `struct` module if you want to convert multiple variables at once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading integers from binary file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1163459/608639), [How to convert a string of bytes into an int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/444591/608639), etc.

Comment: inverse: `b'\x03'[0]`

Comment: If you have a bytes object `var = b'abc'`, then `var[0]` would return `97` and `var[1]` `98`, and so on.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

Assuming you're on at least 3.2, there's a [built in for this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes):

> **`int.from_bytes`**( *`bytes`, `byteorder`, *, `signed=False`* )
>
> ...
>
> The argument *`bytes`* must either be a bytes-like object or an iterable
> producing bytes.
>
> The *`byteorder`* argument determines the byte order used to represent the
> integer. If *`byteorder`* is `"big"`, the most significant byte is at the
> beginning of the byte array. If *`byteorder`* is `"little"`, the most
> significant byte is at the end of the byte array. To request the
> native byte order of the host system, use `sys.byteorder` as the byte
> order value.
>
> The *`signed`* argument indicates whether two’s complement is used to
> represent the integer.

```
## Examples:
int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x01', "big")                         # 1
int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x01', "little")                      # 256

int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x10', byteorder='little')            # 4096
int.from_bytes(b'\xfc\x00', byteorder='big', signed=True)  #-1024
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a difference between `int.from_bytes` and `ord(b'\x03')` for single bytes/chars?

Comment: The only difference I can think of is that `int.from_bytes` can interpret the byte as a signed integer if you tell it to - `int.from_bytes(b'\xe4', "big", signed=True)` returns -28, while `ord()` or `int.from_bytes` in unsigned mode returns 228.

Comment: use `sys.byteorder` to pass the byte order while calling.

Comment: @KrishnaOza - that depends. If you're converting bytes that were encoded on a remote system, say because you're receiving them over a network connection, there's no guarantee that the remote system's native byte order matches yours. This has been a significant historical problem.

Answer (score 21):

Lists of bytes are subscriptable (at least in Python 3.6). This way you can retrieve the decimal value of each byte individually.

```
>>> intlist = [64, 4, 26, 163, 255]
>>> bytelist = bytes(intlist)       # b'@\x04\x1a\xa3\xff'

>>> for b in bytelist:
...    print(b)                     # 64  4  26  163  255

>>> [b for b in bytelist]           # [64, 4, 26, 163, 255]

>>> bytelist[2]                     # 26
```

Answer (score 10):

`list()` can be used to convert bytes to int (works in Python 3.7):

```py
list(b'\x03\x04\x05')
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: does not work in python 2.7

Comment: This answer is perfectly valid, because it does work in Python 3.7

Comment: In addition, `tuple()` also works in case you want an immutable sequence.

Answer (score 2):

```
int.from_bytes( bytes, byteorder, *, signed=False )
```

doesn't work with me 
I used function from this website, it works well

https://coderwall.com/p/x6xtxq/convert-bytes-to-int-or-int-to-bytes-in-python

```
def bytes_to_int(bytes):
    result = 0
    for b in bytes:
        result = result * 256 + int(b)
    return result

def int_to_bytes(value, length):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, length):
        result.append(value >> (i * 8) & 0xff)
    result.reverse()
    return result
```

Comment: This should be equivalent to doing `int.from_bytes(bytes, 'big')`

Answer (score 2):

In case of working with buffered data I found this useful:

```py
int.from_bytes([buf[0],buf[1],buf[2],buf[3]], "big")
```

Assuming that all elements in `buf` are 8-bit long.

Answer (score 1):

convert bytes to bit string

```
format(int.from_bytes(open('file','rb').read()),'b')
```

Answer (score -1):

An old question that I stumbled upon while looking for an existing solution. Rolled my own and thought I'd share because it allows you to create a 32-bit integer from a list of bytes, specifying an offset.

```
def bytes_to_int(bList, offset):
    r = 0
    for i in range(4):
        d = 32 - ((i + 1) * 8)
        r += bList[offset + i] << d
    return r
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#convert bytes to int 
    def bytes_to_int(value):
        return int.from_bytes(bytearray(value), 'little')

    bytes_to_int(b'\xa231')
```