# Is there a way to convert bit to int?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert a string of 0s and 1s (bits) into an integer.

I've tryied this:

```py
str(int(bin(stringofOandI)))
```

and I've tried this too:

```py
str(int(bin(str(stringofOandI))))
```

but none of these works

It is supposed to convert this (just an example):
in the EntryField : 01001101
in the console: 77

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bytes to int - Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009653/bytes-to-int-python-3)

Comment: Please look at the above question. Maybe that can help you. Otherwise, try `ord()`. Also, please do a little bit of research before posting a question. I found the link instantly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert base-2 binary number string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928240/convert-base-2-binary-number-string-to-int)

Answer (score 1):

In the `int()` function specify base 2:

```
b = '01001101'
i =   int(b, 2)
print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a binary string (a string containing 0s and 1s), you need to use [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), and you should pass `2` to the parameter `base` which by default is `10`:

```py
>>> stringofOandI = '01001101'
>>> int(stringofOandI, 2)
77
```