# Converting raw binary data to unsigned int in python

Tags: python, codec, mnist

I am trying to read MNIST data without API. I have seen the format from  http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/. For the training set label file, the bytes from 4 to 7 should indicate the number of samples i.e., 60000.

```
train = open('train-labels-idx1-ubyte','rb')

train.read(4)

bytecode = train.read(4) // this gives the bytecode.
```

I want to convert that to int, I am new here, can I get some help?

Comment: If you need to convert Bytes to int in Python please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009653/convert-bytes-to-int).

Comment: If you need to convert Bytes to other numeric types, use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module