# How can I extract numbers from video frames using Tesseract OCR?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am interested in extracting numbers from standardized videos (always HD resolution @ 1920x1080, 30 FPS) I have. Numbers always appear in fixed sections of the screen and are never missing.

My approach would be to:

1. Save video  in frame by frame PNGs
2. Load a single PNG frame
3. Select the areas of interest (there are a four sections I want to
   extract numbers from; each section might need their own image manipulation; always in the exact same pixel range)
4. Extract numbers using Python and Tesseract-OCR
5. Store values in data frame

Examples of two of the sections are:

[image]

[image]

I have installed Python (I'm an R user) and tesseract and can run the Tesseract examples well (i.e. I have confirmed my setup works).

However, when I run the following commands on the top image [247] Tesseract is not able to extract the number, while you'd think it's easy to extract as the text is very clear.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import os
import cv2
import argparse


img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Luc/Videos/Monza GR4 1.56.156/frames/frame1060_speed.png")

cv2.imshow("RAW", img)
cv2.waitKeyEx(0)
cv2.destroyWindow()


imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imshow("RBG", imgRGB)
cv2.waitKeyEx(0)
cv2.destroyWindow()


imgBW2WB = cv2.bitwise_not(imgRGB)
cv2.imshow("White black swapped", imgBW2WB)
cv2.waitKeyEx(0)
cv2.destroyWindow()


(thresh, blackAndWhiteImage) = cv2.threshold(imgBW2WB, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("Remove some noise", blackAndWhiteImage)
cv2.waitKeyEx(0)
cv2.destroyWindow()


pytesseract.image_to_string(blackAndWhiteImage, 
                            config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```

The output is:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(blackAndWhiteImage, 
                            config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
Out[15]: '7\n\x0c'
```

Comment: I presume you're using the latest tesseract? The old one is pretty bad...

Comment: I'm using Tesseract V5.0.0 and Python 3.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this Python code accordingly:

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import numpy as np

def getText(filename):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    HSV_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    h,s,v = cv2.split(HSV_img)
    v = cv2.GaussianBlur(v, (1,1), 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(v, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    cv2.imwrite('{}.png'.format(filename),thresh)
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, ksize=(1, 2))
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel)
    txt = image_to_string(thresh, config="--psm 6 digits")
    return txt
    

text = getText('WYOtF.png')
print(text)
text = getText('0Oqfr.png')
print(text)
```

Here getText() function will take path of the png image file. After converting to HSV domain it will take the value component as v and then perform the Gaussian Blur before thresholding. You can try varying the kernel size of the dilate function accordingly to your images. The two images were given as input to the code above, and below is the output.

Output

```
247
0.10.694
```

#### Thresholding results

WYOtF.png

[image]
[image]

0Oqfr.png

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `bytes` to `int`.
Please test:

`int.from_bytes(b'7\n\x0c', byteorder='little')`

Looks like you are getting the 47 from 247 right but not the 2. Cheers.

Check this for more info [Convert bytes to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009653/convert-bytes-to-int)

Comment: When I run int.from_bytes(b'7\n\x0c', byteorder='little') I get:  Out[22]: 789047 not 47.

Comment: @Luc check the selected area. I had the same problem when the area was bigger than the actual target.

Comment: OK, I can definitely reduce the space on the top, right and bottom, but not the left, as the values range from 0-999

Comment: Also, it is a coincidence that when I change --psm to 8 I get: Out[41]: '247\n\x0c' ??? Turning this from bytes to int gives a nonsense number EDIT: I tried with a different frame and get the exact number 164 read as Out[54]: '164\n\x0c'