# Why two bytes types cannot be xored

Tags: python, xor

I need a functionality to xor all possible single bytes with a bytestream. I have that function:

```
def byteChallenge(text):
    for i in range(0xff):
        res = ([bytes([i]) ^  bytes([a])  for a in text])
        print(res)
```

where `text = bytes.fromhex(hexstring)`

and I am getting an unreasonable error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'bytes' and 'bytes'
```

both `bytes[i]` and `bytes[a]` are of the same bytes type.
How i fix that?

Comment: Related: [Convert bytes to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34009653/11082165)

Comment: it shouldn't be the only solution to convert it to integers. Why xor cannot operate directly on bytes?

Comment: What would `b'\01\02' ^ b'\01'` be? An`int` already has an implied padding (0s on the left) for XORing two values. No such implicit padding exists for bytes, so `bytes` doesn't try to pick one. It just doesn't support `^` at all, and lets the user decide on an appropriate conversion to `int`.

Comment: why that works then: `bytes([_x ^ _y for _x, _y in zip(a, b)])` where a,b are similarly bytes fetched from `bytes.fromhex` ?

Comment: Because `_x` and `_y` are `int` values. A `bytes` iterator produces integers, not single-byte `bytes` values.

Comment: `list(b'\01\02\03') == [1,2,3]`, not `[b'\x01', b'\x02, b'\x03']`.

Comment: By the way, `range(0xff)` won't give you every possible byte value, for that you need `range(0x100)` because a range never includes its endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

You can XOR arbitrary `int` value because, as arbitrary precision values, any pair of `int` values can be thought of as bit sequences of identical length, with high-order 0s padded as necessary to the smaller of the two value.

`bytes`, though, just represent sequences of bytes with *no* semantics about what those bytes mean. If the two values were of equal length, you *could* compute the XOR of pairwise elements. But if the value are of *different* lengths, what should the result be? You could pad the shorter sequence, but with what byte(s)? And should the padding be higher- or lower-order bytes in the sequence?

There's no obvious answer, so `bytes` doesn't try to impose one. It simply doesn't support XOR, leaving it to the user to interpret the bytes in a way that XOR makes sense.