# Convert a bytearray to a integer array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have the following `bytearray` in Python:

```
bytearray(b'\x02\xcb\x00\n\x02\xcb\x00\n\x02\xcb\x00\n\x02\xcb\x00\n')
```

I want to convert the hexa values of the `bytearray` to an array of integer values, by converting `\x02\xcb\x00` to an integer 183040 for each '\n'.

It should look like:

```
[183040, 183040, 183040, 183040]
```

How can I get it?

I did a `list(bytarray)` and it just worked for single values not composite ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytes to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009653/convert-bytes-to-int). You just need to split it. And your byte string is malformed with the last slash.

Comment: Using a newline character to separate binary data, seems unwise.

Comment: FYI, you have an extra `\\` at the the end of your bytes string. Python will interpret this as an escape char for the quotation mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
b = bytearray(b'\x02\xcb\x00\n\x02\xcb\x00\n\x02\xcb\x00\n\x02\xcb\x00\n')
int_list = [int.from_bytes(n, "big", signed=False) for n in b.split(b'\n')[:-1]]
print(int_list)
```

Output:

```
[183040, 183040, 183040, 183040]
```

Just be careful about the *endianess* `["big", "little"]` and the sign.

Comment: The same problem as the other answer. It assumes `\n` will be there only as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You might be tempted to split the bytes by the newline character, but the ASCII value of the newline character (10), might show up as part of the integer byte.

The only way this can work, is if the newline character always delimits 3 bytes of the integer.

In this case, you need to iterate over the bytes and take the 3 bytes out of every 4 bytes.

```
b = b"\x02\xcb\x00\n\x02\xcb\x00\n\x02\xcb\x00\n\n\n\n\n"

numbers = []
for i in range(0, len(b), 4):
    if b[i+3] != 10:
        raise ValueError("Expected a newline character")
    numbers.append(int.from_bytes(b[i:i+3], "big"))
    
print(numbers)
```

Prints out:

```
[183040, 183040, 183040, 657930]
```

Comment: I agree that using a newline character to separate binary data is not a good idea but IMHO this is not a valid answer, the request is clearly different.

Comment: What request is different?

Comment: your solution requires the input to be grouped in integers of 3 bytes, if the question requires to group by `\n` then this might change, right? this is why we agreed that it's not a good idea...

Comment: I mentioned that constraint. Otherwise it can't work, for reasons I also mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the bytearray on newline and then map it to integers

```
xs = bytearray(b'\x02\xcb\x00\n\x02\xcb\x00\n\x02\xcb\x00\n\x02\xcb\x00\n')

result = []
for line in xs.split(b'\n'):
  result.append(int.from_bytes(line))

result[:-1]
```

since `xs.split(b'\n')` return a list ending with `bytearry(b'')` you should drop the last element.

Comment: no way this works, the argument `byteorder` in function `from_bytes()` is required for this purpose

Comment: I expect `b'\x0a\x0a\x0a\n\x0a\x0a\x0a\n\x0a\x0a\x0a\n\x0a\x0a\x0a\n'` to return `[657930, 657930, 657930, 657930]` not `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.